# Expressing two complex variables with constraints in terms of a single one without

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have two complex variables $u$ and $v$ with the constraints

$|u|^2+|v|^2=1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ and $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ uv=|uv|\ $.

With two constraints there are basically two degrees of freedom, and I should be able to express everything in terms of a single complex coordinate $z=u/v$. Then I'd like to write $u$ and $v$ in terms of $z$ but so far I am unable to.

I am able to get partly there using the equations above as follows:

$1+|z|^2=\frac{|v|^2+|u|^2}{|v|^2}=|v|^{-2}$

$uv=|uv|=\frac{|u/v|}{|v|^{-2}}=\frac{|z|}{1+|z|^2}$

$u^2=uv\frac{u}{v}=z\frac{|z|}{1+|z|^2}\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ u=\pm\  z^{1/2}\sqrt{\frac{|z|}{1+|z|^2}}$

$v^2=uv/\frac{u}{v}=z^{-1}\frac{|z|}{1+|z|^2}\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ v=\pm\  z^{-1/2}\sqrt{\frac{|z|}{1+|z|^2}}\ $.

But I need an expression that determines $u$ and $v$ completely and not just up to a sign. Can anyone see how to get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If $u$ and $v$ satsify your equations, then $-u$ and $-v$ do too (and give the same value of $z$).

Comment: Oh yeah that's true.. But you need _both_ $u\rightarrow-u$ and $v\rightarrow-v$ to get the same $z$, is there any way to show that this corresponds to both signs positive or both signs negative in $u(z)$ and $v(z)$ (as I assume it does)?